# "abort trap: 6" when importing matplotlib.pylab

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, ipython, enthought

I'm having trouble importing matplotlib.pylab as I get the following:

```
In [2]: import matplotlib.pylab 
Abort trap: 6
```

I have installed EPD

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
MacBook-Pro-2:bin$ which ipython
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython
```

And when I run it it works as usual:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin$ ipython
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:14:05) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I also cloned matplotlib from github and installed it via the usual `python setup.py install` but I think my system can't work out which matplotlib to use?

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:
/Users/user/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/python:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

I cut it down to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:/bin:
/opt/X11/bin:
/usr/local/git/bin:
/usr/texbin
```

but I still get the same error. How could I strip the above down so it just uses the necessary packages within EPD so it doesn't cause a conflict with other python/matplotlib installs? I've looked elsewhere on the web relating to the `Abort Trap: 6` error but there isn't anything helpful so far.

Also when I install matplotlib from source It seems to want to write into:

```
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I think this is the cause of the issue. I have manually written into the EPD distro the source matplotlib files.

One final thing which might be related:

I had to use my brew installed python to install wxWidgets (brew install wxWidgets) which installed the following:

```
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/wxmac-3.0.0.0.tar.bz2
```

Then I changed $PATH to link back to EPD since it did not have wx installed. I could not install wxWidgets using EPD ipython/python active for some reason. Would not using EPD for this install break anything?

Comment: This is primarily an OSX problem, not a python or mpl problem.

Comment: ACK! You are trying to mix brew'ed and non-brewed setups. You are asking for trouble. Unless you are forced to use Enthough, I recommend removing it and installing Python, Pip, Matplotlib with Homebrew.